# Huawei EC156 mobile broadband not working with Network manager on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit

Tags: network-manager, 14.04, mobile-broadband, huawei, wvdial

Related to [Getting HUAWEI Mobile Broadband E173 to work in Ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419651/getting-huawei-mobile-broadband-e173-to-work-in-ubuntu-13-10) .
I have the same situation with the huawei ec156 modem .With wvdial it works perfectly with /dev/ttyUSB0 but with Network manager for some reason it uses /dev/ttyUSB2 and fails to connect (even though it is detected by NW manager ) . May be it is as case of way the code/config is implemented.  I would really like to use the Network manager for easier connectivity and to use the data card as a Wifi hotspot using network sharing .

**Lsusb**

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 12d1:140b 
Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. EC1260 Wireless Data Modem HSD USB Card
```

**nmcli d**

```
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE        
**ttyUSB2    cdma              disconnected** 
eth0       802-3-ethernet    unavailable  
wlan0      802-11-wireless   disconnected
```

**Logs while pluggin in device**

```
Apr 24 12:23:04 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.246348] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340038] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=1505
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340047] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340052] usb 2-1.1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340057] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340062] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340747] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy kernel: [ 3951.340976] scsi16 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 8: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
Apr 24 12:23:05 quaddy mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 8 was not an MTP device
Apr 24 12:23:06 quaddy kernel: [ 3952.341150] scsi 16:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Apr 24 12:23:06 quaddy kernel: [ 3952.350107] sr1: scsi-1 drive
Apr 24 12:23:06 quaddy kernel: [ 3952.350410] sr 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Apr 24 12:23:06 quaddy kernel: [ 3952.350564] sr 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Apr 24 12:23:06 quaddy usb_modeswitch: switch device 12d1:1505 on 002/008
Apr 24 12:23:06 quaddy kernel: [ 3952.665155] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 8
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.689071] usb 2-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.783434] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=140b
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.783443] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.783448] usb 2-1.1: Product: HUAWEI Mobile
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.783453] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: HUAÿWEI TECHNOLOGIES
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.783458] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.784391] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.784608] option 2-1.1:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.784925] usb 2-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.785385] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.785691] option 2-1.1:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.785943] usb 2-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.786271] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.786561] option 2-1.1:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.786822] usb 2-1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.786933] usb-storage 2-1.1:1.3: USB Mass Storage device detected
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy kernel: [ 3955.787542] scsi20 : usb-storage 2-1.1:1.3
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 9: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 9 was not an MTP device
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Apr 24 12:23:09 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  (ttyUSB0): port attributes not fully set
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy usb_modeswitch: switched to 12d1:ffffffff on 002/008
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.787823] scsi 20:0:0:0: CD-ROM            HUAWEI   Mass Storage     2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.789660] scsi 20:0:0:1: Direct-Access     HUAWEI   SD Storage       2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.798813] sr1: scsi-1 drive
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.799032] sr 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.799130] sr 20:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.799427] sd 20:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
Apr 24 12:23:10 quaddy kernel: [ 3956.835675] sd 20:0:0:1: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Apr 24 12:23:11 quaddy usb_modeswitch[3860]: usb_modeswitch: switched to 12d1:140b on 2/9
Apr 24 12:23:12 quaddy usb_modeswitch[3860]: usb_modeswitch: add device ID 12d1:140b to driver option
Apr 24 12:23:12 quaddy usb_modeswitch[3860]: usb_modeswitch: please report the device ID to the Linux USB developers!
Apr 24 12:23:13 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  (ttyUSB1): port attributes not fully set
Apr 24 12:23:13 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <info>  Creating modem with plugin 'Huawei' and '3' ports
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  (ttyUSB2): port attributes not fully set
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <info>  Modem for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1' successfully created
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  Couldn't load unlock retries: 'SIM not inserted'
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  couldn't load list of Own Numbers: 'MDN from NV memory appears invalid'
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <warn>  couldn't load current Bands: 'Couldn't build bands array from '3''
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy ModemManager[701]: <info>  Modem: state changed (unknown -> disabled)
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <warn> (ttyUSB2): failed to look up interface index
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <info> (ttyUSB2): new Broadband device (driver: 'option1' ifindex: 0)
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <info> (ttyUSB2): exported as /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <info> (ttyUSB2): device state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <info> (ttyUSB2): deactivating device (reason 'managed') [2]
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <info> NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Apr 24 12:23:23 quaddy NetworkManager[897]: <info> (ttyUSB2): device state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none') [20 30 0]
```

This device has support for additional  SIM hence ttyUSB2 & ttyUSB0 is CDMA

I have tried the solution here [configuring USB modem( Huawei EC156) in ubuntu 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/362815/configuring-usb-modem-huawei-ec156-in-ubuntu-13-10) also .

Question is "Can I manually configure Network manager to use ttyUSB0 instead of ttyUSB2"

May be one work around would be to give some options to specify  the correct modem and  the AT commands  just like a normal  dialer .

Comment: Have you installed `usb-modeswitch` ?

Comment: I see usb_modeswitch binary present in 14.04 . Any thign to try out with modeswitch ?

Comment: Install following packages `sudo apt-get install python-pysqlite2 python-pysqlite2-doc python-pysqlite2-dbg hal python-messaging wader-core`

Comment: Im not sure what that has to do with usb_modeswitch and usb modem . If you are suggesting some steps ; can you list out all the steps ?

Answer (score 0):

It has been identified as wireless data modem mode by the computer. So it is needed to swithch that mode to mobile broadband mode. That mode switch is done by the package `usb-modeswith`. Confirm weather usb-modeswitch is been installed by:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep -v deinstall
```

This will list the installed packages. See weather `usb-modeswitch` is thers.(Go through the alphebatical order)

If it present, then try with install the all the packages that Huawei Broadband Modems need to function properly.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pysqlite2 python-pysqlite2-doc python-pysqlite2-dbg hal python-messaging wader-core
```

Then also install all the packages that `network-manager` needs to work properly. [(Its dependencies)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/network-manager)

```
sudo apt-get install multiarch-support dbus dnsmasq-base iproute2 iputils-arping isc-dhcp-client libc6 libdbus-1-3 libdbus-glib-1-2 libglib2.0-0 libgudev-1.0-0 libmm-glib0 libnl-3-200 libnl-genl-3-200 libnl-route-3-200 libnm-glib4 libnm-util2 libpolkit-gobject-1-0 libsoup2.4-1 libsystemd-login0 lsb-base policykit-1sysv-rc  udev wpasupplicant
```

Comment: I see "usb_modeswitch" binary already pre-installed with 14.04 . network-manager is also pre-installed . I have tested with  another Huawei make (different model) dongle provided  another carrier . And network manager works flawlessly .

Comment: Model of other working Huawei modem is E1731

Comment: Follow this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/316600/224082

Comment: No luck with that approach . Actually Network manager detects the device and I can see the device  listed in the Network Connection dialogs .
 If you notice the logs usb mode switch also happens .
 It seems to be picking /dev/ttyUSB2 instead of  /dev/ttyUSB0  .